# fill arrayList with dat file

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class MadLib
{
private ArrayList<String> verbs = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> nouns = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> adjectives = new ArrayList<String>();

public MadLib()
{
    loadNouns();
    loadVerbs();
    loadAdjectives();
    out.println(nouns);
}

public MadLib(String fileName)
{
    //load stuff
    loadNouns();
    loadVerbs();
    loadAdjectives();


    try{
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println("Houston we have a problem!");
    }
}

public void loadNouns()
{
    nouns = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        //nouns = new ArrayList<String>();
        String nou = "";
        Scanner chopper = new Scanner(new File ("nouns.dat"));

        //chopper.nextLine();
        while(chopper.hasNext()){
            nou = chopper.next();
            out.println(nou);
            nouns.add(nou);
            //chopper.nextLine();
        }
        //chopper.close();
        out.println(nouns.size());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println("Will");
    }       
}

public void loadVerbs()
{
    verbs = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        Scanner chopper = new Scanner(new File("verbs.dat"));
        while(chopper.hasNext()){
            verbs.add(chopper.next());
            chopper.nextLine();
        }
        chopper.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println("run");
    }
}

public void loadAdjectives()
{
    adjectives = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        Scanner chopper = new Scanner(new File("adjectives.dat"));
        while(chopper.hasNext()){
            adjectives.add(chopper.next());
            chopper.nextLine();
        }
        chopper.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
}

public String getRandomVerb()
{

    String verb = "";
    int num = 0;
    num = (int)(Math.random()*(verbs.size()-1));
    verb = verbs.get(num);
    return verb;
}

public String getRandomNoun()
{

    String noun = "";
    int num = 0;
    if(nouns == null){
        loadNouns();
    }
    double rand = (Math.random());
    num = (int)(rand * (nouns.size()-1));
    out.println(num);
    noun = nouns.get((int) num);
    out.print(noun);
    return noun;
}

public String getRandomAdjective()
{

    String adj = "";
    int num = 0;
    num = (int)(Math.random()*(adjectives.size()-1));
    adj = adjectives.get(num);
    return adj;
}       

public String toString()
{
    String output = "The " + getRandomNoun() + getRandomVerb() + " after the " + getRandomAdjective() + getRandomAdjective() + getRandomNoun() + " while the " + getRandomNoun() + getRandomVerb() + " the " + getRandomNoun();
   return output;
}
}
```

and here's one of the .dat files (the other 2 are the exact same aside from the specific words they contain):

```
dog
pig
chicken
building
car
person
place
thing
truck
city
state
school
student
bird
turkey
lion
tiger
alligator
elephant
```

My issue is that I can't get any of my `arrayLists` to read in their appropriate .dat files and from my POV, my code seems like it should do that

**UPDATE**

current output aside from the absence of "Will" (I removed that line):

```
run
[ ] 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at MadLib.getRandomNoun(MadLib.java:130)
at MadLib.toString(MadLib.java:147) 
at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source) 
at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
at Lab16d.main(Lab16d.java:18)
```

Comment: Do you get any output at all? Even if its "Will"? You should try e.getMessage() in that println

Comment: yes, I do get output for that but it seems to be that the ArrayList isn't filling up

Comment: What exceptions are thrown, if any? What exactly is the output you Do get? You have a lot of repeated code in there as well

Comment: just used the e.getMessage in my println() statement and it claims that it can not find the specified file....

Comment: Then probably the file isn't in the execution path as you are assuming. Try modifying the filename for the absolute path of the file or try to work out the relative path.

Comment: just resolved it..... I had to tell it to look in a sub folder of where it was trying to look. Thanks for your help tho!

Comment: I tidied it up and resolved another potential source of exceptions for you- take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class MadLib {
    private ArrayList<String> verbs = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> nouns = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> adjectives = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MadLib a = new MadLib();
        System.out.println(a.toString());
    }

    public MadLib() {
        loadAllWords();
        System.out.println(nouns);
    }

    public MadLib(String fileName) {
        loadAllWords();

        try {
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void loadAllWords() {
        loadNouns();
        loadVerbs();
        loadAdjectives();
    }

    public void loadNouns() {
        nouns = loadFile("nouns.dat");
    }

    public void loadVerbs() {
        verbs = loadFile("verbs.dat");
    }

    public void loadAdjectives() {
        adjectives = loadFile("adjectives.dat");
    }

    public ArrayList<String> loadFile(String filename) {
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            Scanner chopper = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            while (chopper.hasNext()) {
                words.add(chopper.next());
                // just calling nextLine will cause an exception at the end of the file unless you have an blank line there on purpose, so this makes sure it does
                if (chopper.hasNext()) {
                    chopper.nextLine();
                }
            }
            chopper.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return words;
    }

    public String getRandomWord(ArrayList<String> words) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int num = rand.nextInt(words.size());
        String word = nouns.get(num);
        System.out.println(word);
        return word;
    }

    public String getRandomVerb() {
        if (verbs == null) {
            loadNouns();
        }
        return getRandomWord(verbs);
    }

    public String getRandomNoun() {
        if (nouns == null) {
            loadNouns();
        }
        return getRandomWord(nouns);
    }

    public String getRandomAdjective() {
        if (adjectives == null) {
            loadNouns();
        }
        return getRandomWord(adjectives);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "The " + getRandomNoun() + " " + getRandomVerb() + " after the " + getRandomAdjective()  + " " +  getRandomAdjective()  + " " +  getRandomNoun() + " while the " + getRandomNoun()  + " " +  getRandomVerb() + " the " + getRandomNoun();
    }
}
```